# displaying values in UILabel...?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uilabel, xcode4.3

I have a UILabel and i have a uint16_t. How can I display the uint16_t value in the label? If I have:

```
 IBOutlet UILabel *answerField;
```

And I have:

```
uint16_t value;
```

And I do:

```
 [answerField setText:value];
```

I get an error. How can I display my uint16_t in my label?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
answerField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", value];
```

or

```
[answerField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", value]];
```